# How to download file on click of button in GWT?

Tags: gwt, download

I am beginner..for trial i used following code..
my txt file i kept on location `D:\test.txt`

what parameters should i give in place of "?"

```java
downloadButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) 
{
        Window.open(?);    
 }
});
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From window.open() you need to call a servlet like the following code..

```
Window.open(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()
                + "ntPdfDownload?myParam=" + String.valueOf(document.getId()), "", "");
```

Then in servlet you can get the value of myParam and download it.

Answer (score 1):

Must be of such parameters:

```
Window.open(“d:/test.txt”,"test","");
```

The meaning of the parameters:

`“d:/test.txt”` - the URL to file.

`"test"` -  the name of the window.

`""` - the features.

Comment: Thanks for reply.but its not recognising "/"
thats where problem is!!

how to proceed?

Comment: Write the stacktrace please. Try to specify the path to your file as `file:///d:\test.txt`

Comment: sorry but this is also not working.. its not recognising forward slash.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Complete example to download a .xls FILE USIGN GWT,apache-poi

- Environment : GWT SDK 2.4
- Spring 3.0.2M
- JAVA : 1.7

Needed Jar file to create .xls file :: poi-3.0.1-FINAL.jar

```
exportButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        String link = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "myfiledownload";
    }//onClick
});//addClickHandler
```

now at the browser when the user hits button exportButton then the control navigates to web.xml and searches for url-pattern that ends with /myfiledownload

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>fileDownload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sbabamca.server.FileDownloadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fileDownload</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/myfiledownload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

After execuiting the code in web.xml the controls tries to execute the servlet with name FileDownloadServlet

### SERVER SIDE

**FileDownloadServlet.java**

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.metadata.ClassMetadata;
import com.fpix.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil;
import com.fpix.util.date.MyDate;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyFileServlet extends HttpServlet {
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
Session session;
Transaction tx = null;


    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "deprecation" })
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

            resp.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=users.xls");
            try {

                sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
                if(!sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().isOpen())
                {
                    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                }
                else
                {
                session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
                }
                tx = session.beginTransaction();
                tx.begin();

                Query qry = session.createQuery("from com.fpix.dto.User u ");
                ArrayList<com.fpix.dto.User> u = (ArrayList<com.fpix.dto.User>)qry.list();

                Query qry1 = session.createQuery("from com.fpix.dto.Profile p ");
                ArrayList<com.fpix.dto.Profile> p = (ArrayList<com.fpix.dto.Profile>)qry1.list();

                /*
                 * code to get the column name of User and Profile Entity
                 */
                ClassMetadata cm = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(com.fpix.dto.User.class);
                String userAttributes[] = cm.getPropertyNames();

                ClassMetadata cm1 = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(com.fpix.dto.Profile.class);
                String profileAttributes[] = cm1.getPropertyNames();

                 HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
                 HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Excel Sheet");
                 HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);

                 rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("id");
                 /*
                  * code to create the columns names in .xls file
                  */
                 int j = 0;
                 for(int i=0;i<userAttributes.length;i++){
                     j = i;
                     if(!userAttributes[i].equalsIgnoreCase("profileData") )
                             rowhead.createCell((short) ++j).setCellValue(userAttributes[i]);
                    }//for

                 for(int i=0;i<profileAttributes.length;i++){
                     if(!profileAttributes[i].equalsIgnoreCase("userData"))
                        rowhead.createCell((short) ++j).setCellValue(profileAttributes[i]);
                 }//for


                 int index = 1;
                 for(int i=0;i<u.size();i++){
                         HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) index);

                         row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(u.get(i).getId());
                         row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(u.get(i).getUser());
                         row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(u.get(i).getPassWord());
                         row.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(u.get(i).getType());
                         row.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(u.get(i).getRole());
                         row.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue(u.get(i).getProfile());
                         row.createCell((short) 6).setCellValue(u.get(i).getEmail());
                         row.createCell((short) 7).setCellValue(MyDate.timeStampToString(u.get(i).getDor()));
                         // set the Profile data to the excel sheet cells
                         row.createCell((short) 8).setCellValue(p.get(i).getRollNo());
                         row.createCell((short) 9).setCellValue(p.get(i).getFname());
                         row.createCell((short) 10).setCellValue(p.get(i).getLname());
                         row.createCell((short) 11).setCellValue(MyDate.timeStampToString(Long.parseLong(p.get(i).getDoj())));  
                         row.createCell((short) 12).setCellValue(MyDate.timeStampToString(Long.parseLong(p.get(i).getDob())));
                         row.createCell((short) 13).setCellValue(p.get(i).getBloodGroup());
                         row.createCell((short) 14).setCellValue(p.get(i).getPhoto());
                         row.createCell((short) 15).setCellValue(p.get(i).getPhone1());
                         row.createCell((short) 16).setCellValue(p.get(i).getPhone2());
                         row.createCell((short) 17).setCellValue(p.get(i).getAddress());
                         row.createCell((short) 18).setCellValue(p.get(i).getCity());
                         row.createCell((short) 19).setCellValue(p.get(i).getPin());
                         row.createCell((short) 20).setCellValue(p.get(i).getState());
                         row.createCell((short) 21).setCellValue(p.get(i).getCountry());
                         row.createCell((short) 22).setCellValue(p.get(i).getGrade());
                         row.createCell((short) 23).setCellValue(p.get(i).getGroups());
                         row.createCell((short) 24).setCellValue(p.get(i).getAssignCourse());

                         index++;
                 }//for

                 java.io.OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
                 wb.write(out);
                 out.close();
                 System.out.println("Data is Exported to Excel file.");

            }//try
            catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println(" Data cannot be imported :: getImport() :: ImportExportData "+e);
            }//catch


        }//doGet
}//class
```

Comment: All that stuff generating the XLS file is completely irrelevant to the original question which was about a generic file.